# Multiple grep results buffers

Tags: buffers, grep

Let's say I want to grep word1 *and* word2.

If I use the grep command for word1 I get the results in the `*grep*`  buffer.
If I then use the grep command for word2 I loose the old results and get the word2 results in a new `*grep*` buffer.

I want two see the *two* grep buffers (for example `*grep 1*` and `*grep 2*`) at the *same* time: How to get this?

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode mentions `grep-a-lot.el`, but I have never tried it.

Comment: You may use `M-x rename-buffer` in `*grep*` buffer to rename it.

Comment: @EvgenyPanasyuk But then you need to move to another buffer before running grep again, or it will reuse the renamed buffer (emacs 24.5.1)

Comment: @JeanPierre Yes, I also noticed this.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily if you use library [Grep+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepPlus#Grep%2b) ([**`grep+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/grep%2b.el)).

Use **`+`** in your first `*grep*` buffer, followed by **`g`**. The `+` renames the first `*grep*` buffer by appending `<N>` (`N`=2,3,...) to it, and it opens a new buffer named `*grep*`.  The `g` in that buffer then launches a new `grep` command there.

`C-h k +` tells you this:

> **`+`** runs the command **`grepp-new-grep-buffer`**, which is an interactive
>       compiled Lisp function in `grep+.el`.
>
> It is bound to `+`, `menu-bar grep grepp-new-grep-buffer`.
>
> (grepp-new-grep-buffer)
>
> Rename current grep buffer and switch to new buffer `*grep*`.
>   Current buffer must be a grep buffer.  It is renamed to `*grep*<N>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the word1 result in some temporary file then do another grep for word2.

Comment: Have you tried that? I found that if I stay in this saved buffer, it will be reused for the next grep.

Comment: @JeanPierre If you go back to the directory you want to grep, you don't get this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe your grep's with a double pipe ('||'). This might be a alternative.

```
 M-x grep 
 grep -nrH 'word1' ||  grep -nrH 'word2'
```

The results of word1 will appear and afterwards the results of word2.
BUT, both in the same *grep*-buffer...

Comment: That doesn't sound like what OP is requesting. I think the request is to have two separate grep buffers, one for `word1` matches and one for `word2` matches, not a single grep buffer for matches of both `word1` and `word2`.